# Windows Store developer license as student

Tags: licensing, windows-store

Is there an option to get Windows Store developer license for free (or with discount) as student? By default, individual license in my country (Latvia) costs 14 EUR. Account registration [link](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/programs/join).

I am interested in Windows Phone app development.

While searching through internet, I found some articles, but they seem to be old enough and are not working anymore.

Comment: did you try this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alicerp/2013/05/03/students-how-to-set-up-your-free-windows-store-developer-account-with-dreamspark/

Comment: Yes, I tried, but MS changed something, because there is not such navigation node as "app development" right now (or in my region??). This is [link](http://i.imgur.com/85K2QN9.png) to screenshot.

Comment: i just took a closer look and only dreamspark is free for as far as i understand, a developer licence costs money. Then again it's only 14 euros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join tech rewards formerly DVLUP and earn points by doing some of the challenges.

https://rewards.msdn.microsoft.com/

Example challenge
https://rewards.msdn.microsoft.com/challenge/9a6b40f0-3e02-4f1f-876e-fe35e3bf308d

Use the points to create a developer account.

https://rewards.msdn.microsoft.com/reward/19c92d82-618d-4df0-9b00-aec495b97fd4

Comment: Thank you. This looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there used to be a free account for students through DreamSpark. Unfortunately the free developer account for the Windows Store was removed from DreamSpark a few weeks ago. Although 14 € / $ 19 isn't that expensive it might still be a barrier for some. Tech Reward as Ken mentioned might be an alternative way for some people.

Answer (score 0):

> DreamSpark has been discontinued.
>  [Microsoft Imagine](https://imagine.microsoft.com/) is the
>   alternate for it.

You can get free developer account for the lifetime if you are a student.
You have to submit the proof that you are a student after creating a account of Microsoft

**[Here is the link](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/Catalog/WindowsStoreDevAccount) and follow the steps required.**

Microsoft provides many things free for student. [Here is the link](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/Catalog) of their entire catalog for student.